# How to style dynamically generated Select2 dropdowns after the page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 for dropdown styling from http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/ .

I have several dropdowns on the page which are styled correctly using the following:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#dropdown1").select2();
    $("#dropdown2").select2();
});
</script>
```

Now, I have another option on the page where it allows the user to add as many dropdowns as they want for additional options, the following way:

```
      <img src="images/add.png" title="Add Row" border="0" onclick="addRowToCountryPrice('',''); return false;">
      <input type="hidden" name="TotalLinesCountry" id="TotalLinesCountry">
      <script> 
        var arr = new Array();
        var ind=0;
        function showCountryDrop(name1,sel, param){
        var dval="";
        dval = "<select name=\"" + name1 + "\" id=\"" + name1 + "\" class=\"countriesclass\">";
        dval += "<option value=\"\">Select Country</option>\r\n";
            selVal = (sel==0001) ? "selected=\"selected\"" : " " ; 
            dval += "<option value=\"0001\" " + selVal + ">United Kingdom</option>";

            selVal = (sel==0002) ? "selected=\"selected\"" : " " ; 
            dval += "<option value=\"0002\" " + selVal + ">United States</option>";

            selVal = (sel==0003) ? "selected=\"selected\"" : " " ; 
            dval += "<option value=\"0003\" " + selVal + ">Albania</option>";

            selVal = (sel==0004) ? "selected=\"selected\"" : " " ; 
            dval += "<option value=\"0004\" " + selVal + ">Algeria</option>";

        dval +="</select>"; 
        return dval;
        }
        function addRowToCountryPrice(country,price) { 
            var tbl = document.getElementById("tblCountryCurrency");
            var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
            var iteration = lastRow;
            var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
            var cellVal = "";
            var cellLeft;
            var i=0;
            arr[ind] = (iteration+1);   
            cellLeft = row.insertCell(i++);
            cellLeft.innerHTML = showCountryDrop("countryDrop_" + ind,country);
            cellLeft = row.insertCell(i++);
            var price = (price!=0) ? price : "0.00";
            cellLeft.innerHTML = "<input type=\"text\" name=\"countryPrice_" + ind + "\" id=\"countryPrice_" + iteration + "\" value = \"" + price + "\" size=\"8\">";
            cellLeft = row.insertCell(i++);
            cellLeft.innerHTML = "<img src=\"images/delete.png\" title=\"Delete Row\" border=\"0\" onclick=\" removeRowFromTable(" + ind + "); return false;\">";
            document.getElementById("TotalLinesCountry").value = (parseInt(ind)+1);
            ind++;
        }
        function removeRowFromTable(src)
        {
          var tbl = document.getElementById("tblCountryCurrency");
          var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
          if (arr[src]!="") tbl.deleteRow((arr[src]-1));
          arr[src]="";
          var counter = 1;
           for( i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
               if (arr[i]!="") {
                  arr[i]= counter;
                  counter++;
               }    
            }
            return false;
        }
        </script>
```

While it generates the dropdowns correctly, they are not styled through the class "countriesclass", even if I do a:

```
$(".countriesclass").select2();
```

I also tried

```
dval +="</select>"; 
$(".countriesclass").select2();
return dval;
```

And that seems to be PARTIALLY working in a strange way. When I create the first dropdown, it doesn't get styled. When I create another second dropdown, then the first one gets styled but the second one doesn't. It then doesn't let me create further ones and shows an error.

Any ideas how I could get this working?

UPDATE: jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/y6af098z/2/

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Yes, of course: http://jsfiddle.net/y6af098z/

Comment: your missing a table element with id  `tblCountryCurrency`, could you add that to your jsfiddle

Comment: Oops, my fault. Fixed everything @ http://jsfiddle.net/y6af098z/2/

Comment: Your `$(".countriesclass").select2();` goes off in the document.ready event, so way before the countries select gets created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `$('.countriesclass')` goes off when the document is ready. But the select has not been added to the document yet, then. So no elements are found.

You should look up the added select after the user has clicked on the plus and you've added the select to the dom.

```
$('#plus').on('click', function () {
    $tr = addRowToCountryPrice('Algeria', 0);
    $('.countriesclass', $tr).select2();
});
```

The second argument `$tr` tells jquery only to look in the recently added table row, so that you only select the newly added `select` which is a child of the newly added `tr`. Not the selects in the other rows.

Like @dreamweiver already noted, you should make better use of jquery when creating the dom elements. That's what jquery is good at. I've updated the jsfiddle to show how you can create the select and table row the jquery way.

[<kbd>DEMO</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/07kxzpvv/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your rewrite of this. I couldn't have done it myself! That works even better :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using getelementbyId use getelementbyClass and give each dropdown a class, you can only have one getelementbyid.

Hope this helps. if you want i could send you the code for what you require?

Comment: I will try and look into that, but it might take me a while as I'm not really great with javascript/jquery :)

Answer (score 0):

The `select2` when called was not able to find the dropdown list boxes,because they were added dynamically and hence the those were not visible for the jQuery class selector `$(".countriesclass").select2();`.

This type of behaviour can be overcome by referencing the selector from the document element, rather than referring the element directly like above. so the new selector should be like this

`$(document).find("select.countriesclass").select2();`

Also I have done few tunings in your code.

**Live demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/y6af098z/8/

*Note: one more thing, when using jQuery lib make sure you make the most of it, don't use raw JS code instead use the jQuery equivalent syntax for the same, which would be simple and easy to use.*

Comment: One thing I noticed, is for example if I "+" 4 or 5 dropdowns and then try to "-" them, it only lets me minus one and then it won't let me remove the others ...

Comment: This is not correct. `$('.countriesclass')` works fine. BUT you have to evaluate it after the select has been added to the dom, not before.

Comment: @user1227914: the minus operation was not working because the `removeRowFromTable`  was not properly programmed to do so. the selective dropdowns can be removed by this one liner ` $(this).closest('tr').remove();`.

Comment: @flup: my solution also works fine, except for the minus operation as i said before there was unnecessary code in it.

Comment: Yes, the fiddle works fine. But the answer text is incorrect.  You don't need `$document.find()` at all.